# How can I keep data in an EditText from updating?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am currently working on an application which read some database, display it on my application (text and image) and I want it to be able to send email containing a certain quantity of items provided by my database.

For the moment, the layout is pretty much finished, I can read data from the database and display it on my application. What I struggle with is the following : I have a RecyclerView in which are several EditText (the number of these EditText depends of the number of the items in the databse). I can enter number in my EditText but when I scroll down these numbers disappear.

After some research, I came across TextWatcher. I set up one watching the EditText but its functions are not entered when I type something in my EditText.

MainActivity.java :

```js
//inside MainActivity class
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //mylist is the xml file in which the EditText with id Quantite is 
    //defined
    setContentView(R.layout.mylist);
    final EditText quantiteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Quantite);

    quantiteText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Entering onTextChanged" + s.toString());
            int position = (int) quantiteText.getTag();
            //Produit is a class containing a field quantite and a 
            //function setQuantite
            Produit produit = produitList.get(position);
            produit.setQuantite(s.toString());
            mAdapter.update(position, produit);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Apparence"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Titre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Code_article"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Code_article"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Designation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Designation"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Quantite_par_carton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Quantite par Carton"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Just here so that the next linearlayout is far on the right -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/QuantiteText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Quantité"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Quantite"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java :

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private List<Produit> produitList;
    private static List<String> mEditTextValues = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Produit> produitList) {
        this.produitList = produitList;
        for(int i = 0; i < produitList.size(); i++)
        {
            mEditTextValues.add("I'm editText number" + i);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //System.out.println("Entering onBindViewHolder");
        Produit produit = produitList.get(position);
        holder.titre.setText(produit.getTitre());
        holder.code_article.setText(produit.getCode_Article().toString());
        holder.designation.setText(produit.getDesignation());
        holder.quantite_par_carton.setText(produit.getQuantite_par_carton());
        holder.quantite.setText(produit.getQuantite());
        Picasso.get().load(produit.getApparence()).into(holder.apparence);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return produitList.size();
    }

    //
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void initialise(List<Produit> produitList) {
        System.out.println("Entering update");
        this.produitList.clear();
        this.produitList.addAll(produitList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(int Position, Produit produit) {
        this.produitList.remove(Position);
        this.produitList.add(Position, produit);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EditText mEditText;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Quantite);

            mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if(mEditText.getTag()!=null){
                        mEditTextValues.set((int)mEditText.getTag(),charSequence.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

There is no output error but no System.out.println() message are shown, and values entered in the EditText aren't kept.

Comment: `System.out.println()` is used in Java, not in Android. Use `Log.d()` rather. And paste the adapter's `update` method as well.

Comment: hi Vucko, thanks for your reply. I didn't know that, I will try to change it if necessary !
I have updated the code for my adapter in the code !